# Programmatically open Viewer/Magnifier window in ArcMap 10.2+

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, add-in

Is there a way to programmatically open Viewer/Magnifier etc. windows of ArcMap from Add-In? 
I am using 10.2, but anything 10.2+ will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for (ArcGIS 10.5.1)?

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication Application = this.Hook as ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication;
ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.MapViewerWindowFactory mvw = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.MapViewerWindowFactoryClass();
mvw.Create(Application);
```

As an alternative you could use the tool to create the viewer window

```
//Searching the command
UID uid = new UIDClass();
uid.Value = "{709608E3-5C7E-11D2-87BB-0000F8751720}";
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid, false, false);

//Executing the command
if (commandItem != null)
{
     if (commandItem.Name == "Browse_NewMapInset")
     {
           commandItem.Execute();
     }
 }
```

Please have a look at the command reference [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/10.5/net/webframe.htm#858a508c-b771-467c-81e6-c6aa72d88f9c.htm)

Comment: yes. exactly! Actually already found it somewhere, just forgot to post here. Thank you very much, hope it helps others cause it was really hard to find. ^__^